# R, removing the bagged samples to generate out of bag sample

Tags: r

I'm trying to set up voting in a bagged model based on performance on the out of bag sample.

```
construct.annet = function(trainset,n,p=1){
  annet.struct = vector(mode="list",length=n)
  cat("Constructing Agregate Neural Network with ",p,"\n")
  for(i in 1:n){
    cat("iteration ",i,"\n")
    bsamp = trainset[sample(p*dim(trainset)[1],replace=T),]
    annet.struct[[i]] = nnet(class~.,data=bsamp,size=sample(4:12,1),maxit=1000)
  }
  return(annet.struct)
}
```

Printing iterations is just to tell me how long things are taking.  As far as why I'm randomly varying the size of the hidden layer, it seemed like the thing to do at the time.

What I want to do is add in another line after building the model on each iteration, where I test the model on the out of bag sample, and then record its predictive accuracy.  Then I'll use that data to weight the class percentage votes on the final model. (lower performing models get less weight, etc)

The trouble is, I can't figure out how to remove the bootstrapped samples from the incoming data.  And my google-fu clearly isn't helping.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is using indices to samples drawn into the bootstrap subset instead of directly extracting these samples:

```
ibsamp <- sample (nrow (trainset), replace = TRUE)
annet.struct[[i]] = nnet (class ~ ., data = trainset [ibsamp, ],
                          size = sample (4 : 12, 1), maxit = 1000)
```

You can then use `subset` to find out which samples were *not* included into the training set

```
itest <- setdiff (seq_len (nrow (trainset)), ibsamp)
test [[i]] <- predict (annet.struct [[i]], newdata = trainset [itest, ])
```

(I'd suggest renaming `traindata` into just `data` for clarity)

Comment: I see now, you're not actually sampling the observations, merely the row numbers.  In which case, it wouldn't make sense to multiply by p in the numbers to be sampled from.  (p is left over from a different model, where i was using a sample size less than n.)  Thanks, this worked perfectly.

Comment: @user24926: yes, I was wondering a bit about that `p` but decided to leave it as it was in your code. I now removed it.